# Dynamic array of structures in C++/ cannot fill a dynamic array of doubles in structure from dynamic array of structures

Tags: c++, function, double, structure, dynamic-arrays

Sorry for my bad english)
I created a dynamic array of structures. This structures contains dynamic array of doubles.
When I add the structure, I fill it this way
The number of sides and the length of the side are filled in calmly, but when it comes to the vertices, or rather to one vertex (along which I have to restore the rest), after entering any number, the program crashes

```bash
struct regular_polygon {
    int count_sides;
    double length;
    double square;
    double perimeter;
    double *x = new double[count_sides];
    double *y = new double[count_sides];
};



void SetData(regular_polygon* reg_pol, int amount, int* output)
{
    cout << "Enter count of sides:" << '\n';
    cin >> reg_pol[amount-1].count_sides;
    bool flag = false;
    if (reg_pol[amount].count_sides > 2) flag = true;
    while (flag == false)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect! Sides must be more than 2. Try again" << '\n';
        cin >> reg_pol[amount].count_sides;
        if (reg_pol[amount].count_sides > 2) flag = true;
    }


    cout << "Enter length of the side:" << '\n';
    cin >> reg_pol[amount].length;
    flag = false;
    if (reg_pol[amount].length > 0) flag = true;
    while (flag == false)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect! Length must be more than 0. Try again" << '\n';
        cin >> reg_pol[amount].count_sides;
        if (reg_pol[amount].length > 0) flag = true;
    }

    cout << "Enter vertex coordinates" << '\n';

    cout << "Enter x:" << '\n';
    cin >> reg_pol[amount - 1].x[ 0];   /// ТУТ ОШИБКА

    cout << "Enter y:" << endl;
    cin >> reg_pol[amount - 1].y[ 0];
    coordinates(reg_pol, amount);
}


    cout << "Enter vertex coordinates" << '\n';

    cout << "Enter x:" << '\n';
    cin >> reg_pol[amount - 1].x[ 0];   /// There is an error
```

I tried to replace dynamic array of doubles to static array of doubles, but it didnot help, unfortunately

Comment: `double *x = new double[count_sides];
    double *y = new double[count_sides];` You allocate arrays of an undetermined size, it results in undefined behavior. Doesn't the compiler warn you about that?

Comment: *contains dynamic array of doubles* Dynamic array of doubles is `std::vector<double>`, `double *x = new double[count_sides];` is a valid but likely incorrect code.

Comment: You appear to be incorrectly assuming that `double *x = new double[count_sides]` will cause magical resizing of the dynamically allocated array whenever the value of `count_sides` changes.  That is simply not the case.   It accesses the current value of `count_sides` and uses that value in the `new` expression - only at the time when an instance of `regular_polygon` is created.      If you want a "dynamic array" (one that grows when needed) then you MUST explicitly write code to explicitly resize it whenever needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Compiler didn't warn me, I work in Code:Blocks. By the way, which IDE would you recommend? I am student, and I am not a programmer, so I did this silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate those dynamically allocated arrays when your object is initialized and `count_sides` has a value. Since this is C++, you can give your struct a constructor.

Assuming `square` and `perimeter` are calculated from the number of sides and length of each side:

```
struct regular_polygon {
    int count_sides;
    double length;
    double square;
    double perimeter;
    double *x;
    double *y;

    regular_polygon(int count_sides, double length)
    : count_sides(count_sides), 
      length(length),
      square(...),
      perimeter(...),
      x(new double[count_sides]),
      y(new double[count_sides])
    { }
};
```

Now you also need to worry about a destructor and the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

You also probably want to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) rather than raw C-style arrays.